# Looking for Equivalent of "Select Database and Select Session" query from Teradata in Google Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have one Teradata code where following two sqls are used inside the procedure. These variables are then used as a parameter to another Select query.

set l_db   = DATABASE;
SET V_EXEC_SESSIONNO = SESSION;

Now as a part of migration, I would like to convert this sql into Google Bigquery. After research, I found Bigquery has system variable such as @@session_id, @@dataset_id, @@dataset_project_id etc. For getting session_id in bigquery, I had to specifically set SESSION MODE ON and then only "Select @@session_id" query returns a value. And for DATABASE, when I am trying to use simple statement such as **"Select @@dataset_id"**, it returns **null**. Also If I tried it inside procedure after setting Session mode On, still it doesn't return any value. So can you please help me how can I retrieve the same functionality as Teradata in Google Bigquery for these two Teradata Built-In functions.

Thanks,
Sachin